# How to change jspinner date min and max values from (database) variables?

Tags: java, swing, max, min, jspinner

Basically this is the problem, **I pull some data** set from the database, and **populate combobox** with it.

So like you can see in this shoot http://prntscr.com/7bscob. Min and max jspinner values SHOULD depend on comboBox **selected item**.

So what I've tried to do is to set a minimal value dynamically, but it sends an `IllegalArgumentException` at the line where I did that.

```
for(int i=0; i<turniri.size(); i++)
            {
                if (turniri.get(i).getNaziv().equals(selectedTurnir)) 
                {
                    t=turniri.get(i).getId();
                    long l = turniri.get(i).getDatumPocetka().getTime();
                    spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1431986400000L), new Date(l), new Date(1433109600000L), Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
                }       
            }
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: Thank you for making me read it once again !!! :D I will update question with call stack so that everyone can pay atention on that, my default data (first value) was before my min value, thats why an exception was thrown

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `long l = turniri.get(i).getDatumPocetka().getTime()` is somehow incorrect.

According to the error value in the SpinnerDateModel must be between min and max.

```
new SpinnerDateModel(new Date(1431986400000L), new Date(l), new Date(1433109600000L), Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
```

So your value is 1431986400000L

Min is l

and max is 1433109600000L

CHeck the numbers and adapt accordingly